# Forgetful functor applied to a module

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

I try to find a left adjoint to the forgetful functor $U: R-Mod \longrightarrow Ab$. I considered a functor $F:Ab \longrightarrow R-Mod$ defined by $F(G)=Hom(U(R),G)$. I'm not so sure that in this case $Hom(U(R),G)$ is a $R$-module since I must define the operation $(r,f)\rightarrow rf$ where $(rf)(s)=f(rs), \forall s\in R$ but by applying the forgetful functor to $R$, I forget about the multiplication of $R$ so $rs$ seems to not exist. Am I missing something?

Comment: The adjoint is not the same as inverse, so the fact that you don't know what $rs$ is not necessarily a problem. The adjoint here will be "free R-module generated by given abelian group". Think about what it means and try to describe it formally.

Comment: This functor doesn't have a right adjoint (e.g. because it doesn't preserve coproducts). Do you mean the left adjoint?

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake.